# Get compiled scss from @monaco-editor/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

Im using @monaco-editor/react editor module in reactjs , I know how to get a value(code) from editor but here I am using SCSS language so is there a way to get compiled css version

```
const editorRef = useRef(null);

    <Editor
                            height={height}
                            path={file.name}
                            defaultLanguage={file.language}
                            defaultValue={file.value}
                            //defaultLanguage="html"
                            //defaultValue={String(component)}
                            theme="vs-dark"
                            onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
                            onChange={handleEditorChange}
                          />
  function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    editorRef.current = editor;
  }
  function handleEditorChange() {
   let val =  editorRef.current.getValue()
  }
```

**My language is SCSS so I am looking for compiled CSS as response of getValue**

Comment: monaco-editor is an editor. It's not the editors job to handle transpiling/compiling of code. You need a different tool for that.

Comment: @super do you know any tool like that ?